# Imagemagick Crop image borders for lot of images with different sizes

Tags: imagemagick

I have a lot of images. Size of images are different.

I need to write the **one** imagemagick commandline operation to crop the borders of each image (for example, 10px of each edge).

Basic usage of [-crop](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop)  reuire to know the image geometry - it's not usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -shave

```
  convert montage.png -shave 10x10 montage.png
```

Comment: It's work. Thank you. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#shave